# How to use startup_script_file in Packer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, packer

I can not understand how to use startup_script_file in Packer. In [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/googlecompute.html) I read this:

> A startup script can be provided via the startup_script_file or 'startup-script' instance creation metadata field.

But without an example, it tells me not that much. I do not know whether I can do it like so in my configuration file (inside builders block):

```
"metadata" {
    "startup_script_file": "path to file"
}
```

Or should I use it like so:

```
$ packer build -startup_script_file 'path to file' config.json
```

If I can set it inside my configuration file, should I set something else in provisioners block to make it work? Unfortunatelly, documentation says too little about this and does not provide any example. At least, I could not find it.

Comment: The first example is wrong since the `metadata` key is `startup-script` and should be the script content not a file reference. The second example is wrong since there is simply no such flag to packer.

Comment: Therefore, I wish they fixed documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can either inline you startup script in the Packer template using the `startup-script` `metadata` parameter or you can provide the startup script as a file using the `startup_script_file` option.

Example - Inline:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "googlecompute",
    "metadata": {
      "startup-script": "<your startup script here. Be careful with json escaping.>"
    }
  }]
}
```

Example - Separate startup script:

```
{
  "builders": [{
    "type": "googlecompute",
    "startup_script_file": "scripts/gce-startup-script.sh"
    }
  }]
}
```

I recommend going with the last version since Json escaping soon gets tricky for even very short scripts. The only real reason to chose the former option is if you need interpolation of (Packer) *user variables* in the startup script.

Comment: And if you are provisioning a Windows image be sure to read the docs for Windows with the `googlecompute` builder.

Comment: It seems, like it is still incomplete. How will this `gce-startup-script.sh` script appear in `scripts` folder of the image? Probably, we should first export this file to the image.

Comment: It's not a reference in the image, it's a reference in to a file on the machine running Packer, relative the template file.

Comment: This is a complete Windows GCE example https://github.com/Diabol/packer-demo/blob/master/windows-cloud.json

Comment: I checked it and unfortunatelly it does not work. My startup script just clones some remote github repository and runs an application. But after I enter into server shell (server is built from this very packer image), I can not even find a repository cloned from github. And application is not running either.

Comment: It works as it should. There is probably something you misunderstood. Send a email to the packer tool mailing list (see the Packer web page) and and you'll get some help.

Comment: I think, I understood it right. Inside my builders block, instead of metadata property I now have startup_script_file property, whose value is path to the local bash script (local in terms of my host machine on which I run packer). And this bash script, which starts with `#!/bin/bash`, has just one line - `git clone https://github.com/.../app.git`. This command obviously should create `app` folder inside virtual machine on startup, but for some reason it does not.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have permissions to clone that repository, or is missing the git package..

Comment: If I do it by hand, when enter the shell on virtual machine, it is ok. And git repository that I clone from is public.

Comment: Send your full template to the email list and we can have a look.